# What is the keycode for the Dashboard key on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, remapping

The F4/Dashboard key has two modes and (presumably) two different key codes.  The first mode is as the Dashboard key, which predictably enough brings up Dashboard.  The second mode is as F4, which can by invoked by holding down the Fn key while pressing the key.

The keycode for F4 is [118](http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20050809161107602).  I'd like to find the keycode for the Dashboard key so I can remap my Dashboard key ala [33844](https://superuser.com/questions/33844), and maybe even the keycodes for the other "special" keys such as Exposé, Vol Up/Down, and Desktop.

Unfortunately, tools such as Full Key Codes don't seem to be able to intercept and print out these particular keys.  How else could I find the keycode for the Dashboard key?

**Note:** I am NOT trying to remap the Dashboard functionality to one of the Fn keys via System Preferences, nor am I trying to "flip" my Fn and Special keys using System Preferences or Function Flip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about this, but I think I read somewhere that the Dashboard key doesn't act like a normal key. The keyboard firmware, instead of sending the keystroke to the computer, tells the computer to launch Dashboard. As such, the "special" keys don't have key codes. That said, if someone else has different information…

Comment: I think so too. I have tried to help mike in the past but I could find him a solution that he liked.

Comment: Thanks Benjamin.  Hm, we'll see if someone turns up some other info.  I certainly hope you're wrong! ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too sure about what you wanted to do but here is what I noticed.

### Basic needs

Actually, <kbd>F4</kbd> is the default shortcut for **Launchpad** in the `System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Launchpad & Dock > Show Launchpad`.

As for the **Dashboard**, the default shortcut is <kbd>F12</kbd> in `System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Launchpad & Dock > Mission Control`.

With these two settings, you should be able to achieve what you need.

### Advanced needs

If you need more, you can look into the [Karabiner Software for OSX](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/), it contains a lot of pre-configured remappings, but most of all, it has an **EventViewer** in the *Misc & Uninstall* tab that shows you what are the keycodes of what you pressed. It could be useful to get the actual keycodes of what you want (except if they are captured by the system before the Karabiner application, but that's another story).

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

I use a standard Windows keyboard, and activating Dashboard is also done via F4. I think the standard code for F4 is the one you're looking for; my keyboard has no special firmware to speak of, yet it can activate Dashboard without a problem.

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

Using achedeuzot's suggestion to use Karabiner Elements Event Viewer, here's what my Late 2013 Macbook Pro (MacbookPro11,3) reports for the various action keys:

```
  112 display_brightness_decrement
  111 display_brightness_increment
65543 mission_control
65542 launchpad
65544 illumination_decrement
65545 illumination_increment
  180 rewind
  205 play_or_pause
  179 fast_forward
  226 mute
  234 volume_decrement
  233 volume_increment
```

The power button on the end does not report a keycode to the event viewer.