# Change mapping of function keys on a Mac keyboard

Tags: macos

I don't use dashboard much, the hardkey for dashboard is mostly useless for me, is there anyway to associate the dashboard key to some other operations like show 'Spaces'

Answer (score 1):

See this tutorial: [Remapping function keys](http://www.xlr8yourmac.com/tips/remap_function_keys.html)
 and this question: [How to remap “Dashboard” key to show the Desktop on OSX [Snow] Leopard?](https://superuser.com/questions/33844/how-to-remap-dashboard-key-to-show-the-desktop-on-osx-snow-leopard)

Comment: And [Documenting com.apple.symbolichotkeys.plist - The macosxhints Forums](http://hintsforums.macworld.com/showthread.php?t=114785).